# count in mysql query not correct because using pivot tables - converting rows to columns

Tags: mysql, count, pivot-table

I have the following query that returns count incorrectly due to pivot table use (3-4 rows in additional value table causes count to be incorrect)

SQL:-

```
select
     count(o.model_id) as qty,
    o.model_id,
    bd.brand_name,
    pd.product_name,
             MAX(IF(oinfokey.name = 'Colour'    , oinfokeyvalue.value , NULL)) AS colourName,
             MAX(IF(oinfokey.name = 'Grade'     , oinfokeyvalue.value , NULL)) AS gradeName,
             MAX(IF(oinfokey.name = 'Network'   , oinfokeyvalue.value , NULL)) AS networkName,
             MAX(IF(oinfokey.name = 'Condition' , oinfokeyvalue.value , NULL)) AS conditionName
From
    `order` o 
INNER JOIN
    product pd
ON
    pd.id  = o.model_id
INNER JOIN
    brand bd
ON
    bd.id  = pd.brand_id
INNER JOIN
    order_additional_information oinfo
ON
    oinfo.order_id  =  o.id
INNER JOIN
    order_additional_information_key oinfokey
ON
    oinfokey.id  = oinfo.order_additional_information_key_id
INNER JOIN
    order_additional_information_value oinfokeyvalue
ON
    oinfokeyvalue.id  = oinfo.order_additional_information_value_id     

GROUP BY 
    o.model_id
```

Output is:-

```
qty model_id    brand_name  product_name    colourName  gradeName   networkName conditionName
3   320 LG  KP235   Brown   Brand New   Unknown 
3   393 Blackberry  Curve 8520  Black   14 Day  3 (Three)   
4   854 Apple   iPhone 4S 16GB  Green   Brand New   Orange  POT - GOOD LCD
3   1087    Apple   iPad 4 64GB WiFi    Bronze  Grade B Unknown 
3   1182    Samsung Ch@t 357 S3570  Black   Grade B Unlocked    
6   1713    Nokia   5500 Sport  Blue    Grade C Vecton
```

How can I correctly get the count from order table, the count result should be:-

```
Count - Model ID
1 - 320,
1 - 393,
2 - 854,
1 - 1087,
1 - 1182,
2 - 1713
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **DISTINCT** in select:

```
count(DISTINCT o.id) as qty,
```

Comment: changed model id to o.id, you count number of different orders for each model

Comment: if 'DISTINCT o.id' shows you 3 for 320, that means that you have 3 orders for 320. Without table data I can not think of anything else.

Comment: sorry vadchen,  its working perfectly fine with distinct o.id...thanks very much.. keep it up. thanks again